# How can you determine whether a JavaScript object is a list?

Tags: javascript, list, types, javascript-objects

`typeof foo` will just evaluate to `'object'` whether foo is a list `[]` or a dictionary `{}` or any kind of object. How can one tell the difference?

Comment: [`Array.isArray`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray)

Comment: It has been answered numerous times

Comment: when I search this question, nothing comes up. It doesn't matter if the question was answered 12 years ago if the post where it was answered doesn't show up on a search. The question that this one is marked as a duplicate of, asks with the word "array", so maybe thats why, but of course javascript has two different kinds of arrays so its not clear even then

Comment: Are you saying that none of the other answers are valid because you asked about "list" and not "array"? If you didn't find something in a search does that mean it doesn't exist? Of course not. The message above simply states : *"This question already has answers here: "*

Comment: no, the other one is definitely valid and answers my question perfectly. I'm saying that right now, if you search using the term "list" you will likely not find the answer. And since javascript has two kinds of arrays, using the term "list" seems pretty likely for a lot of people, so a lot of people will not find the answer. I didn't, thats why I asked here.

Comment: Float32Array, Uint8Array, etc, vs []. Typed arrays vs what I've been calling "lists"

Comment: @apc518 they are still arrays. No such concept as "list" by defaulr

Comment: thats great, but not everyone knows that, including myself until now. My point is, if someone searches for this problem with the term "list", they will probably not find the answer, which is a very reasonable thing to do seeing as other languages call their variable-length ordered O(1) addressable iterable collections "lists" (e.g. python)

Comment: So if they search term "list" then this question could turn up and the link above will take them to solutions

Comment: It is what it is.....someone probably decided it didn't show research effort

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript, arrays are objects, as is the value `null`.  You simply use the `Array.isArray` method to see if anything is one.

```js
const obj = {}
const arr = []

Array.isArray(obj) // false
Array.isArray(arr) // true
```